# Auto-Populating field based on another field in ArcGIS Online?

Tags: arcgis-online, arcgis-pro, arcgis-web-appbuilder, feature-service

I am trying to use the Damage Assessment hosted feature layer and dashboard for local government.

One of the fields that we use a domain (combobox) for is the Inspector who looks over the damage. Is it possible to auto-populate the phone and email fields for the inspector once the object is created in ArcGIS Online?

I know there are ways to do this with the calculate field tool, but that is not automatic. I am honestly not sure if this is even possible.

Do you know if it is?

Comment: Depending on your situation, and better way to do this would be to use a relation or join between your 'Damage' layer and a separate 'Inspector' table.  Join the two on the value in the 'Inspector Name' field.  You should always avoid duplicating data where possible, and use database relationships instead.

Comment: The question remains if join possible in arcgis online

Comment: FAQ: Does ArcGIS Online support joins and relates?: http://support.esri.com/technical-article/000012168

Comment: How to join features - http://doc.arcgis.com/en/arcgis-online/analyze/join-features.htm